# Analytic function on complement of closed unit disk onto open unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, analytic-functions

Does there exist an analytic function whose domain is the complement of the closed unit disk and whose range is the open unit disk?

I am studying John B. Conway's book *Functions of One Complex Variable* for my own amusement. One of the exercises following Chapter III, Section 3, asks whether the open unit disk can be mapped conformally onto the punctured open unit disk. I solved that one (it's true), and then asked myself whether the converse were true as well. I immediately realized that that question is equivalent to whether the complement of the closed unit disk can be mapped conformally onto the open unit disk. Then I realized that I didn't even know the answer to the simpler question asked above.

Comment: For information on how to ask here, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g(z)$ any Blaschke product of degree two that is not $cz^2$; then $g$ maps the punctured unit disc holomorphically onto the unit disc since $g(0)=g(w)$ for some $w \ne 0$. Then $f(z)=g(1/z)$ will map the exterior of the closed unit disc holomorphically onto the open unit disc.

For example $g(z)=\frac{(1-2z)^2}{(2-z)^2}$ is one such Blaschke product, giving

$f(z)=\frac{(z-2)^2}{(2z-1)^2}$

It is considerably more difficult (though doable) to find a conformal such $f$ (in other words with the additional condition that $f'(z) \ne 0, |z|>1$)

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Nice solution. Can you direct me to a source for the conformal function that does the trick?

Comment: Here there is a neat solution which is fairly explicit  https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=complex;action=display;num=1234362106

Comment: Thanks very much.